# TYPO3: how to display content elements from different pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Hopefully, someone knows how I can simplify the following TypoScript so I can pass a list of page ids from the template constant to the template script. say, I have defined a TEASER_IDS = 6,7,9,12,4, and the TypeScript walks thru that list and uses it for the select.pidInList one after the other instead of having to manually create a CONTENT object in the TypoScript for each ID.

```
lib.teaser = COA
lib.teaser {  
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="part">|</div>
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.pidInList = 6
    select.where = colPos=1
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  }
  20 = CONTENT
  20 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="part">|</div>
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.pidInList = 7
    select.where = colPos=1
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  }
}

page.50.30 < lib.teaser
```

It is TYPO3 version 10.4.8

EDIT: new version but I'd like to have the elements be wrapped each, so it results in

```
//this is what it should look like
<div class="header">CONTENT ID 6 colPos 1</div>
<div class="text">CONTENT ID 6 colPos 2</div>
<div class="header">CONTENT ID 7 colPos 1</div>
<div class="text">CONTENT ID 7 colPos 2</div>
<div class="header">CONTENT ID 4 colPos 1</div>
<div class="text">CONTENT ID 4 colPos 2</div>
```

TypoScript now:

```
lib.teaser = COA
lib.teaser {  
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="header">|</div>
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.pidInList = 6,7,4
    select.where = colPos=1
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  }
  20 = CONTENT
  20 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="text">|</div>
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.pidInList = 6,7,4
    select.where = colPos=2
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  }
}

page.50.30 < lib.teaser
```

The code gives me, which makes sense, but I have no idea how to change the code so it gives me the preferred output like mentioned above the new code

```
//this is not what i want
<div class="header">
CONTENT ID 6 colPos 1
CONTENT ID 7 colPos 1
CONTENT ID 4 colPos 1
</div>
<div class="text">
CONTENT ID 6 colPos 2
CONTENT ID 7 colPos 2
CONTENT ID 4 colPos 2
</div>
```

Comment: Ehm, `pidInList` does exactly that: `select.pidInList = 6,7`

Comment: oh yes, thanks. indeed :) however, i'd like to have it wrapped individually. say, currently all content elements get wrapped together. i'll update the question above with some new because there needs to be content elements from multiple colPos

Comment: Do not use two CONTENT objects as they both iterate over all matching CEs. Instead, use the option to overwrite the `wrap` if the colPos has a corresponding value.

Comment: may I ask how this is achived? How can I check if the colPos has a certain value? This is far beyond my knowledge, I think

Answer (score 0):

Do not use two CONTENT objects as they both iterate over all matching CEs. Instead, use the option to overwrite the wrap if the colPos has a corresponding value.

```
stdWrap {
  wrap = <div class="text">|</div>
  override = <div class="header">|</div>
  override.if {
    value.field = colPos
    equals = 1
  }
}
```

( https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/If.html#if )

Answer (score 0):

If you want a loop over the pages where you collect content from different columns you need to build this structure in typoscript.

As you have noticed now you get all content for column 1 from all pages and then all content from column2.

How could you build a loop over the page IDs? we have no `for` loop in typoscript as it is a configuration language and no programming language.

That might be possible with a split on the comma separated list of the ids.

```
lib.teaser = TEXT
lib.teaser {
    # list of page ids:
    value = 6,7,9,12,4
    split.token = ,

    # only one kind of rendering (otherwise use optionsplit to define cases)
    cObjNum = 1
    # example: 1 = first, 4 = last, between: 2,3 alternating
    # cObjNum = 1 |*| 2 || 3 |*| 4
    # cases of rendering:
    1 = COA
    1 {
        10 = CONTENT
        10 {
            stdWrap.wrap = <div class="part">|</div>
            table = tt_content
            select.orderBy = sorting
            # use current value of split:
            select.pidInList.current = 1
            select.where = colPos=1
            select.languageField = sys_language_uid
        }
        20 = CONTENT
        20 {
            stdWrap.wrap = <div class="part">|</div>
            table = tt_content
            select.orderBy = sorting
            select.pidInList.current = 1
            select.where = colPos=1
            select.languageField = sys_language_uid
        }
    }
}
```